# "be about to" and "soon", "immediately"

Tags: grammar

I am wondering whether I can use "be about to" and "soon" or "immediately" in one sentence?
I found online that the following two sentences "The medical team is about to start immediately" and "He is about to leave soon" are wrong.

Comment: Could you provide links to those online sources?

Comment: Yes, you can. The *about to* and the *soon/immediate* are unrelated, they refer to different things. Think again.

Answer (score 1):

Immediately means right now, this instant.

> I am buying that Commemorative His Highness King FAISAL watch immediately! There are only 3 left, and I want one!

Soon means in a short time.

> I am buying that Commemorative His Highness King FAISAL watch soon! There are only 30 left, and I want one.

About to is somewhere between soon and immediately.

> I'll be there soon. I'm about to buy that Commemorative His Highness King FAISAL watch! There are only 6 left, and I want one!

Can you use them in the same sentence? Not if you're describing the same time interval.

Comment: I don’t agree that _about to_ is somewhere between _soon_ and _immediately_. I’d say _immediately_ is quite specific in that it means ‘right now’, but both _soon_ and _about to_ are fairly vague and can easily refer to the same time frame. “About to [verb] immediately” does sound strange and not logical to me; but “about to [verb] soon” does not necessarily. Colloquially, something like, “Hurry up! The movie’s about to start soon!” is quite common (and Googling “about to start soon” gives about 1.2 million results—enough to show that the construction is fairly common).

Comment: In fact, I think, if you force _soon_ and _about to_ to have constrastive meanings in a context, that _about to_ will be in a **shorter** time than _soon_. For instance, I find it fairly natural to say, “We’re not _about_ to leave, but we’ll be going soon” (meaning we’ve still got a bit of time, but not too much); but not, “We’re not leaving _soon_, but we are about to go”.

Answer (score 0):

It *is* possible to construct a valid sentence using those terms together.

Here is one possibility for a sentence that includes *be about to,* *soon,* and *immediately.* I am confident there could be others. Someone might be able to explain the grammatical structures involved, but I will not attempt to do so.

"He is about to leave, soon, if not immediately after the medical team starts."

Comment: +1 This is a good answer. Practical, not opinionated. Nice work. @GMB

Comment: @TecBrat Thanks for the edit. maybe that makes my answer more nearly resemble an answer.

Comment: @ RyeBread I seem to be not capturing the essence of an answer. I'll edit this a bit more and see it that helps. I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: This is technically all within one sentence, true … but it’s ‘cheating’ in that it doesn’t use the different words to refer to the same thing as in the examples in the question and use tricks like “soon, if not immediately, after”. If you split things up into different clauses, you can use _any_ three words in a sentence, more or less. That wasn’t quite the point of the question, though.

Answer (score 0):

Definition of about,

> on the subject of; concerning.

So, it is safe to say that "about" denotes context.

However, about to, is defined as

> Indicates something that will happen very soon; indicates that something is imminent

Soon here, would represent time

> in or after a short time.

The two statements are wrong on the accounts that, "about" does not denote the context but rather, it denotes the length of time - using "to" - before a particular event happens (according to whatever to subject is e.g. leaving or surgery)

About to = soon. Repetition is unnecessary in the English language (Synthesis and Transformation emphasises this value in schools).

John is about (preposition) to leave (verb) = John is leaving (gerund) soon (adverb)

You can use about to, soon and immediately only if you specify context as GMB answered. You cannot say "We are about to leave immediately!" since that would be an oxymoron. In common speech, you would be understood *somewhat* but it doesn't make it correct in any sense. The right way is to say "We are going to leave immediately after dinner!" if the context is not "right this instant" type of immediately.

Adverbs clarify the subject. If you don't have a subject or multiple subjects, it is safer to stick to one, tbh.